# Create a mandatory checkbox

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

Since I force users to accept terms and consitions in my form before submitting it, I would like to create a checkbox in AlpacaJS that prevent form validation until it is flagged. I've not found anything on documentation so wonder if someone has already faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that requiring the value does not do what you want, but given the way Alpaca works, you can get your expected behavior by following the example under "Forms With Custom Buttons" on this page: http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/forms.html

Basically you do your own check before submitting the form using your custom button code.  The example I'm copying here is from validate button in that example (options > buttons > validate):

```
              "validate": {
                "title": "Validate and view JSON!",
                "click": function() {
                    this.refreshValidationState(true);
                    if (this.isValid(true)) {
                        var value = this.getValue();
                        //1. Your checkbox value can be tested in "value"
                        //2. Submit your data
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but altough this approach might work, since Alpaca IS a library to create and validate forms, and a mandatory checkbox is a basic feature, I think there is something I'm missing or an error on my settings: I can't believe it must be done manually.